# Proving an algorithm returns a random bit

Tags: probability

there's a question on my homework I'm not sure how to tackle. I wouldn't want to copy the question word for word but I'll try to be as specific as possible.

I have a coin that is not fair, with probability p of landing on heads. The algorithm is:

```
foo(){
    *Flip coin 2 times*;
    if(heads then tails)
        return 0;
    else if(tails then heads)
        return 1;
    else foo();
}
```

The sample space encompasses all possible sequences of outcomes of foo(). Determine the sample space and prove that foo() returns a uniformly random bit.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say foo returns $0$ with probability $p$ and $1$ with probability $1-p$.  Then we can say $p = (\frac{1}{4}) + (\frac{1}{2})p$, since it immediately returns $0$ in the heads-then-tails case, and it returns $0$ with probability $p$ in the heads-then-heads or tails-then-tails cases.